# How to print the response time in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

Problem Statement: I want to print the the response time (time taken for a request) on the console using a post processer in JMeter, How to do it ?

I have tried with JSR223 post processer, using the following code.

```
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult;


log.info("--------------->",sampleResult.getTime())
```

[image]
And I am getting

```
2021-11-09 15:56:55,632 ERROR o.a.j.e.JSR223PostProcessor: Problem in JSR223 script, JSR223 PostProcessor
javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: sampleResult for class: Script2
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:320) ~[groovy-jsr223-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyCompiledScript.eval(GroovyCompiledScript.java:71) ~[groovy-jsr223-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at javax.script.CompiledScript.eval(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_251]
    at org.apache.jmeter.util.JSR223TestElement.processFileOrScript(JSR223TestElement.java:222) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.extractor.JSR223PostProcessor.process(JSR223PostProcessor.java:45) [ApacheJMeter_components.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.runPostProcessors(JMeterThread.java:940) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:572) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:489) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:256) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_251]
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: sampleResult for class: Script2
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:65) ~[groovy-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoGetPropertySite.getProperty(PogoGetPropertySite.java:51) ~[groovy-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGroovyObjectGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:341) ~[groovy-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at Script2.run(Script2.groovy:10) ~[?:?]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:317) ~[groovy-jsr223-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    ... 9 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You don't have `sampleResult` object in [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor)
2. If you want to print the response time of the **previous** sampler - you need to use `prev` shorthand for the [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html) class instance
3. You need to use [string concatenation](https://dzone.com/articles/concatenate-strings-in-groovy)

So remove all the imports, they're not needed and amend your code to look like:

```
log.info("---------------> " + prev.getTime())
```

More information: [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy)